# How to combine a data frame and a vector

Tags: r

```
df<-data.frame(w=c("r","q"), x=c("a","b"))
y=c(1,2)
```

How do I combine df and y into a new data frame that has all combinations of rows from df with elements from y?  In this example, the output should be

```
data.frame(w=c("r","r","q","q"), x=c("a","a","b","b"),y=c(1,2,1,2))
  w x y
1 r a 1
2 r a 2
3 q b 1
4 q b 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data.frame(lapply(df, rep, each = length(y)), y = y)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you're trying to do, and without too much work.

```
dl <- unclass(df)
dl$y <- y
merge(df, expand.grid(dl))
#   w x y
# 1 q b 1
# 2 q b 2
# 3 r a 1
# 4 r a 2
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
library(combinat)
df<-data.frame(w=c("r","q"), x=c("a","b"))
y=c("one", "two") #for generality
indices <- permn(seq_along(y))
combined <- NULL
for(i in indices){
  current <- cbind(df, y=y[unlist(i)])
  if(is.null(combined)){
    combined <- current 
  } else {
    combined <- rbind(combined, current)
  }
}
print(combined)
```

Here is the output:

```
      w x   y
    1 r a one
    2 q b two
    3 r a two
    4 q b one
```

... or to make it shorter (and less obvious):

```
combined <- do.call(rbind, lapply(indices, function(i){cbind(df, y=y[unlist(i)])}))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, convert class of columns from factor to character:

```
df <- data.frame(lapply(df, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then, use `expand.grid` to get a index matrix for all combinations of rows of `df` and elements of `y`:

```
ind.mat = expand.grid(1:length(y), 1:nrow(df))
```

Finally, loop through the rows of `ind.mat` to get the result:

```
data.frame(t(apply(ind.mat, 1, function(x){c(as.character(df[x[2], ]), y[x[1]])})))
```